# Barplot showing differences of two vectors

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have two vectors:

```
a <- [100, 150, 52, 49, 321]
b <- [120, 100, 88, 96, 118]
```

Is there a way using ggplot2 package to plot a barplot which overlaps the two values of the same index for the vectors so that the difference between the two values is highlighted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you want to compare the value with the same index (100 with 120, 150 with 100, and so on). Then:

```
library(tidyverse)
a <- data.frame(value = c(100, 150, 52, 49, 321))
b <- data.frame(value = c(120, 100, 88, 96, 118))

a$com <- 'a'
b$com <- 'b'

df <- rbind(a,b) %>% 
  mutate(index = c(seq(1:5),seq(1:5)))
```

Outputs:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = index, y = value, fill = com)) +
  geom_col(alpha = 0.4, position = "identity")
```

[image]

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = index, y = value, fill = com)) +
  geom_col(alpha = 0.4, position = "dodge")
```

[image]

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = index, y = value, fill = com)) +
  geom_col(alpha = 0.4)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could show the difference of each `index`:

```
library(ggplot2)
a <- c(100, 150, 52, 49, 321)
b <- c(120, 100, 88, 96, 118)
df = data.frame(difference = a - b, index = 1:length(a))
ggplot(df, aes(x = index, y = difference, fill = factor(index))) +
        geom_bar(stat = "identity", show.legend = F)
```

[image]